# Dart Polymer Paper Spinner in Firefox

Tags: dart, polymer, spinner

I am starting to learn about dart and polymer, so was playing with the SDK and IDE. Then I had a problem with Paper Spinner in Firefox when running from a dart project. Here is what i did:

- install Intellij IDEA free latest EAP version 143.379.11 and latest plugin for Dart. I installed Dart SDK 1.12.2 by choco.
- create a new project using "Polymer Web Application".

In Index.html, i insert this into the head section:

```
<script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_spinner.html">
```

Then I insert this into the body section:

```
<div>
  <paper-spinner alt="test"></paper-spinner>
  <paper-spinner active></paper-spinner>
  <paper-spinner></paper-spinner>
  <paper-spinner active></paper-spinner>
</div>
```

I run the above web app in Chrome and could see the spinners. However when i choose firefox, the spinners didn't appear.

Has anyone tried this out?

Comment: I tried it and can reproduce. The [JS demo](http://polygit.org/components/paper-spinner/demo/index.html) works in FF though. This might have been fixed recently in JS but the fix has not yet landed in http://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements. AFAIK a new update roll to use the latest JS elements for the Dart elements is work in progress.

Comment: Thank you Mr Günter Zöchbauer.